# Data not transfering from Ajax to php to mail

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

I followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKq1n-awLcw
On how to implement a working contact form in my website.

Everything went fine, until I sent the first test mails and discovered that the mails are indeed sent, but without any informations : [Empty mail received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dA3B.png).

I'm not an expert in jquery or php, but I get how it works, and I can't seem to find why it is not working as intended.

I tried to tweek some variables here and there, but without any results.

Here is the HTML :

```html
<form id="contactform" class="form-element" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
          
                    <label class="form-field">
                        <span>Name</span>
                        <input id="name" class="form-component" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </label>
            
                    <label class="form-field">
                        <span>Email</span>
                        <input id="email" class="form-component" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </label>
            
                    <label class="form-field">
                        <span>Subject</span>
                        <input id="subject" class="form-component" type="text" name="subjects" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </label>
            
                    <label class="form-field">
                        <span>Message</span>
                        <textarea id="message" class="form-text-area" name="message" autocomplete="off" required></textarea>
                    </label>
            
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <button class="form-submit" type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send an email.">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Here the script :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail(){
            var name = $("#name");
            var email = $("#email");
            var subject = $("#subject");
            var message = $("#message");

            if(isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject) && isNotEmpty(message)){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/contact.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{
                        name: name.val(),
                        email: email.val(),
                        subject: subject.val(),
                        message: message.val() 
                    }, success: function(response){
                        $('#contactform')[0].reset();
                        $('.confirm-title').text("Message sent successfully!");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        function isNotEmpty(caller){
            if(caller.val()=="") {
                caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                caller.css('border', '');
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And finaly here is the PHP document :

```php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

if(isset($_POST['name']) &&  isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name               =   $POST['name'];
    $email              =   $POST['email'];
    $subject            =   $POST['subject'];
    $message            =   $POST['message'];

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/includes/phpmailer/Exception.php";
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/includes/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/includes/phpmailer/SMTP.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // SMTP Settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host         =   "secret";
    $mail->SMTPAuth     =   true;
    $mail->Username     =   'secret';
    $mail->Password     =   'secret';
    $mail->Port         =   secret;
    $mail->SMTPSecure   =   "ssl";

    // Email settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress("secret");
    $mail->Subject      =   ("$email ($subject)");

    $MailBody           =   "From: ".$name."<br>";
    $MailBody           .=   "Email: ".$email."<br>";
    $MailBody           .=   "Message: ".$message."<br>";

    $mail->Body         =   $MailBody;

    if($mail->send()){
        $status = "success";
        $response = "Email is sent !";
    }
    else {
        $status = "failed";
        $response = "Something is wrong: <br>".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
}
```

I do receive the "Message sent successfully!" message on the website.

I already checked the "Transfer data from Ajax to php" post, and everything seems to be fine so..

Comment: I can't help with your problem directly, but the AJAX `success` function is for a successful HTTP request, not for successfully sending a message. Your PHP is might be returning a status of `failed` which you aren't checking in your `success`. Also, your problem can be broken down into two unrelated part, AJAX to PHP, and PHP sending email. Once you are confident that the first is working you can hard-code variables into a page and test the second. Once that's working, glue them together.

Comment: Also, a dynamic FROM is just asking to be listed in the major spam databases. You should only send FROM an email domain that you have permission to send from, and that probably has proper records in place in DNS.

Comment: Okay the comment from Julian is actually the answer. But what do you mean by "dynamic FROM" ? You're talking about the $setFrom() variable ?

Comment: I'm seeing you use `$mail->setFrom()` with a variable which implies it could be anything. (If that's not the case, ignore this.) While technically this is still possible, realistically some/many/most email servers have SPF records and other guards in place to specifically stop other servers from impersonating them.

Comment: Oh okay I see ! Well, I just use this contact form to send an email to myself, and get the name and email of the person completing it. It's for a portfolio so it's no big deal. But thanks anyway, because I'll now need for the mails not to go in the spam folder ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly collecting the values ​​of $_POST

```
$name               =   $POST['name'];
$email              =   $POST['email'];
$subject            =   $POST['subject'];
$message            =   $POST['message'];
```

try this way

```
$name               =   $_POST['name'];
$email              =   $_POST['email'];
$subject            =   $_POST['subject'];
$message            =   $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: This is good spotting! But can you be very literal and specifically say that they are missing the underscore in the global variable? I even had to read it a couple of times before I noticed what you were trying to say.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my english is not very good

Comment: F**k that is the problem. Thanks ! I should have noticed but I was so tired I did not saw the obvious...

Comment: @JulianFagadau, that's okay. Your answer was spot on, but the OP's problem was so subtle that it helps if you can be explicit with the issue, otherwise they're stuck comparing two code blocks.